# MySQLInstallerConsole suddenly failing due to "failing dependencies"

Tags: mysql

I have been using a script for installing MySQL Server that suddenly stopped working... I am installing like this:

```
MySQLInstallerConsole community install -silent server;5.7.14;x64:*:type=config;servertype=Server;openfirewall=true;generallog=true;serverid=3306;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;rootpasswd=%1;installdir="C:\MySQL\MySQLServer-5.7":type=user;username=jlawyer;password=%1;role=DBManager
```

Now I am suddenly getting this:

```
=================== Start Initialization ===================
MySQL Installer is running in Community mode

Attempting to update manifest.
Initializing product requirements
Loading product catalog
Checking for product catalog snippets
Checking for product packages in the bundle
Categorizing product catalog
Finding all installed packages.
Your product catalog was last updated at 01.03.2017 22:48:34
=================== End Initialization ===================



Package MySQL Server 5.7.14 cannot be installed due to failing requirement.

Product installations done.
```

When I run the installer in GUI mode, it automatically downloads and installs dependencies, but how can I get the MySQLInstallerConsole to do this?

Comment: It seem that this started happening when using the MySQLInstallerConsole that comes with the web installer (online installer). I switched to using the offline installer and all is good. So... still an issue, but there's a workaround (that just costs bandwidth).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check requirements by launching installation from given installer manually. I had the same problem and it was just because Visual C++ 2013 64bits was not installed.

FYI, Visual C++ 2013 can be installed silently with `vcredist_x64.exe /q /norestart`

Comment: Well... yes, I could do so. But why does it download and install the dependencies in GUI mode automatically but not in quiet mode? Doing remote installations I can not do it in GUI mode, and it needs to run unattended.

Answer (score 0):

In The user configuration section add the following :-

auth_plugin=mysql_native_password (or whatever authentication type you would like

So you would have the following :-

```
MySQLInstallerConsole community install -silent server;5.7.14;x64:*:type=config;servertype=Server;openfirewall=true;generallog=true;serverid=3306;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;rootpasswd=%1;installdir="C:\MySQL\MySQLServer-5.7":type=user;username=jlawyer;password=%1;role=DBManager;auth_plugin=mysql_native_password
```